# Completing items in ruby on rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have migrated a :completed boolean, I then added it to my form like so (simple_form)

```
<%= f.input :completed, as: :boolean %>
```

This allows me to update completed, not completed in the edit view.

How can I edit the :completed method in my index view? I want to be able to update complete or not complete on the fly.

EDIT:

My Form

```
<%= f.input :completed, as: :boolean, input_html: { class: 'completed', id: @todo.id } %>
```

My View (label has to be after input as per materializecss)

```
<%= check_box_tag todo.id, 'completed', todo.completed?, class: 'completed' %>
<label class="strikethrough">
  COMPLETE
</label>
```

The JS

```
// This could be other events as well, so add/change/remove the event trigger as needed
$(document).on('click', '.completed', function(){
    updateCompleted($(this));
});

function updateCompleted($el) {
   var id   = $el.attr('id'),
       val  = $el.is(':checked');

   $.PATCH({ 
     url: '/todos/'+id, 
     data: { todo: { completed: val } }, 
     success: function(){ whatever }, 
     error: function() { whatever }
   });
}
```

My Controller

```
params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :item, :image, :completed)
```

Comment: So you want to be able to update completed from the index is that correct?

Comment: Yes sir, that is exactly correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to require some AJAX here.  In my experience, doing this is a bit outside of the "rails way", but totally possible.

First, make sure you have the ID of the object somewhere in the dom:

```
<%= f.input :completed, as: :boolean, input_html: { class: 'completed', id: myobject.id %>
```

I used the simple_form syntax since that's what it appears you are using for your form builder.  If not, comment back and I'll adjust the tag.

Secondly, add a jquery event listener:

```
// This could be other events as well, so add/change/remove the event trigger as needed
$(document).on('click', '.completed', function(){
    updateCompleted($(this));
});

function updateCompleted($el) {
   var id   = $el.attr('id'),
       val  = $el.is(':checked');

   $.PATCH({ 
     url: '/your_endpoint/'+id, 
     data: { your_object_name: { completed: val } }, 
     success: function(){ whatever }, 
     error: function() { whatever }
   });
}
```

And in your controller:

```
private

def your_object_params
   params.require(:your_object).permit(..., :completed)
end
```

That's basically it.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. Can I just ask, how do you display the checkbox on the index.html.erb? would it be as <%= check_box_tag todo.completed %>?

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't consider that simple_form might not be the best way to do this since you're not on the edit/new pages.  You can use this API endpoint for rails:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

Comment: Am I right in thinking it would be <%= check_box_tag dom_id(todo), todo.id, todo.completed? %> or completed.nil?

Comment: <%= check_box_tag todo.id, 'completed', todo.completed?, class: 'completed' %>

Comment: Ah thank you - I see where I went wrong there. Now I just have to debunk step 2 and it should be perfect :-)

Comment: @StuartPontins Let me know if you need any help, I think it's fairly straight forward.

Comment: I'm sorry - please do forgive me as this is all new to me. I'm just struggling a little bit. I have changed url to '/todos/'+id but I'm not sure what else to change - is there a resource I can read more about this?

Comment: What are you confused about?  The Rails code or the JavaScript code?  Is one or the other not working?

Comment: The JS I think - I have implemented all of the rails code but I'm assuming I have to amend the JS code somewhere, am I right? e.g. url: '/your_endpoint/'+id, is your_endpoint for example; todos/+id?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work - I'll update my Q with what I have, if you could point me in the right direction that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @StuartPontins are you getting a hit in your rails server?  Is the javascript throwing any errors?  If the JavaScript is broken you should see errors in the console.  If the server is not getting pinged you should see a 404.

Comment: No errors are popping up in the rails server - I've just thought though... would it be todo.complete as the object name? but this gives a syntax error

Comment: Do you have a github repo?

Comment: Give me a bit I'll pull it down and look at it if you havent made any progress

Comment: Not sure what happened to that, but it's gone now.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what happened. I genuinely can't take any more -- I'm going to have to sleep and try again tomorrow my tiny brain is frazzled.

Comment: Nah dude, keep your head up.  Rails has a steep learning curve :) If you need any help ping me on here and I'll try what I can.

Comment: Back for day 2, thanks for the kind words and offer of help. Truly appreciate that. Can I ask what exactly should this be? data: { your_object_name: { completed: val } } the object name am I right in thinking it would be 'Todo'? I did Todo.name to find it, assuming thats class.name, right?

Comment: @StuartPontins In Rails 4.1 you are required to use Strong Parameters to do a mass-attribute update.  In your update action, when you do @todo.assign_attributes(todo_params), you are actually using what's called Strong Parameters.  The line params.require(:todo) is expecting the request body to contain the key "todo" in it.  Hence, data: { todo:  { ... } }.   That should not be the "name" of the Todo object rather it should be "todo" which is the name of the CLASS.  Sorry for the confusion, I may have sent you down the wrong path.

Comment: Ahh how silly of me, that makes much more sense. So it would be 'TodosController' hmm, though this still doesn't provoke any action in the console log so something else must be wrong. Am I right in thinking my endpoint is correct as '/todos/'+id (by the way I use friendly ID would this cause any issue?)

Comment: a few things i have noticed; right now when I go to the edit page the checkbox reads <input class="boolean optional completed" id="16" type="checkbox" value="1" name="todo[completed]"> and when I click the checkbox here I get "Uncaught TypeError: $.PATCH is not a function" each click. My checkbox on the dash reads <input type="checkbox" name="completed" id="completed" value="16" class="completed"> the name is different, but I'm not sure how to make it the same (I assume it has to be?)

Comment: Okay, try switching $.patch to $.post({ ... }).  That should fix your problem.  I forgot jQuery doesn't have method for $.path like $.get or $.post.  See here for more docs:  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Heh, I have got it working to some extent - it works, until I add materialize checkbox :/ I assume because materialize hides the checkbox and uses css to put it there. Any idea how I could fix this issue? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Open up the javascript console and try to locate the checkboxes.  Verify that the checkbox has the ID for your Todo object on it.  Then setup a listener for the checkbox's class.  It really just is a matter of getting your listener to fire correctly.  In Chrome Developer Tools JavaScript Console (google it if you dont know how to use it), you can run your jquery code.  So you can use the console and $('.mycheckbox') or whatever the class/name you're using the select on it.  At the end of the day you might not want to use Materialize to do this.

Comment: Alright - thanks for all of your help - I'll mark answered as it does work without Materialize for anyone else struggling on with this! I owe you a bunch b-d-b!

Comment: just figured it out - the id also has to have the todo.id :-) works like a charm

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will want to make a post to the update action from the index action.  I would use JavaScript but you can also use a hard refresh if you want to stick with rails.  Here is a good intro if you are not familiar with using JS in your rails app.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript.